# Libvirt: AppArmor Profiles Access Error

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-server, libvirt, ubuntu-18.04, app-armor

I have installed `libvirt-daemon` on a fully updated `Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS`. When trying to execute `libvirtd --listen`, the following errors arise:

```
2018-08-24 21:03:18.641+0000: 2855: error : virFileReadAll:1420 : Failed to open file '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied
2018-08-24 21:03:18.641+0000: 2855: error : profile_status:100 : Failed to read AppArmor profiles list '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied
```

The output of `sudo ls -l /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles` is:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 24 13:21 /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles
```

My suspicion is that the permissions of `/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles` should be `555`. The errors seem completely due to misconfigured permissions, as `sudo libvirtd --listen` runs without errors. However, I would rather not run `libvirtd` with root permissions on my system. Disabling `apparmor` would also probably get rid of the error, but I would rather not do that either.

My question is then, is this a misconfiguration error, and if so, is it a misconfigured `libvirt` or a misconfigured `apparmor`? If not, what is the cause of these errors?

Comment: on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, the file /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles is -r--r--r--, and everything is OK! the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: Same problem here. I checked all the permissions of every parent folder and all are set to allow reading for all. profiles is -r--r--r-- but when I do cat profiles, I get permission denied. I can only view it as root.

Comment: I know this is late to the party, but I was able to fix this on my SLES 15 SP5 machine by moving the apparmor read line above the 5 deny lines just above it in the usr.sbin.virtqemud and usr.sbin.libvirtd files.. (restarting apparmor after that) My theory is that the audit deny with globbing on the entire folder is denying the read attempt *before* the line that accepts it can approve. So by moving it earlier in the file we resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into a similar problem. By any chance you had Cockpit installed in your server?